# When I use the copy/paste buttons on my Typematrix 2030 keyboard when using Intellij IDEA, it instead does an insert 50% of the time

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard

#### Setup

- Device: Laptop
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

#### Description

I know this is a weirdly obscure issue and I know I can use ctrl+cxv, but I have a Dvorak layout, so the 'X' 'C' and 'V' are quite far apart. I'm now so used to the other buttons because of this as they're right next to each other, I keep using them unconsciously.
And it's really frustrating seeing my attempt to copy/paste work only 33% of the time and having to redo it over again.

I've understood from [a Typematrix forum post](https://groups.google.com/g/typematrix-user-group/c/Djo1CZAt99I/m/I9ef35m29-EJ) that these keys are linked to
key-sequences.

- Cut: Shift+Delete,
- Copy: Ctrl+Insert,
- Paste: Shift+Insert

This impedes on my work and I'm desperate.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?